# Sqlite get last item where condition does apply in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

How to get the last Item of Database where a Special condition does apply?

```
 var History = (from c in conn.Table<HistoryItem>() select c.Done); //how to get last Item where c.Done is true?
```

Comment: @GrantWinney It just Needs to be the last Item in the Table where Done is true.

Comment: @GrantWinney So there is no id created automatically? When I'm creating a new property of type int  with [key] Annotation, would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to specify an order condition to have `Last` make any sense. Otherwise, it would simply be `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()` (or you can order in the order direction and take `First()`

```
var History = (from c in conn.Table<HistoryItem>() select c.Done)
              .OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault();
```

Would select the *newest* history item. Again, going back to the point about ordering being important.. Whether that's the last or first item is a matter of perspective. It's first if you were to view the change log newest -> oldest, but it's the last in terms of date added.